# Printing current nanosecond of the kernel timer

Tags: c, linux, time, kernel, clock

In my C code, I need to print the current nanosecond of the kernel time. I have searched in this forum and found some tricks but they are not working. The following is my code.

```
#include<sys/time.h>
struct timespec ti;
```

Then when I print the value using

```
(....:%ld\n",ti.tv_nsec);
```

It always print 0. Actually what I am trying to do is to print the current time inside a loop so that I get very accurate timestamp. In my situation I have a lot of packets coming in one second and to compare the specific packet in wireshark and the log, I need very accurate time stamp so that I can identify which packet had error. So can you help me identify my error in this method. I can also use other better techniques to print the current kernel time with such granularity if you can advice any.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You seem to be assuming the problem lies in the *printing* - Most probably, the problem lies in *how you obtain* the value - Show us that code.

Comment: You need to *call* a function (`clock_gettime`) to fill in the current values into the `struct timespec` - additionally you must check the return value.

Comment: Thank you Antti. Can you specify how should I be using the function in my code? Or where can I learn more on how to use that function? Does clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ti); sufficient?

Comment: It depends on what clocks are available on your system.  Try CLOCK_MONOTONIC.